# WPF: Can't get my control to take focus

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, setfocus

I can't seem to get my control to actually take the focus:

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command={Binding SetGridToVisibleCommand} />
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsGridVisible, Converter={con:VisibilityBooleanConverter}}">
    <TextBox Text={Binding MyText} IsVisibleChanged="TextBox_IsVisibleChanged" />
</Grid>
```

**XAML.cs:**

```
private void TextBox_IsVisibleChanged(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement element = sender as UIElement;

    if (element != null)
    {
        Boolean success = element.Focus(); //Always returns false and doesn't take focus.
    }
}
```

---

The ViewModel does it's job of setting the IsGridVisible to true, and the converter does it's job by converting that value to `Visibility.Visible` (I snooped it).

Comment: Wrap your element.Focus() call in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), I'm curious if that fixes it.  (Although might not be a good permanent solution)

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the absolutely minimum needed code (no command, just `Button.Click`; no converter, just binding to a bare `Visibility` property). Maybe something else is interfering in your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all `UIElements` can be focused by default, have you tried setting [`Focusable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) to true before trying `Focus()`?

Comment: Just tried this out... it didn't help. I'm still stumped as to what could be the cause of this.

Comment: The code looks fine and Mohammed A. Fadil could not reproduce the problem, probably there is something in your context which interferes.

Comment: Yup, the control had Focusable=false.

Answer (score 1):

We use this with in our application:

```
public static class Initial
{
    public static void SetFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FocusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
             "Focus", typeof(bool), typeof(Initial),
             new UIPropertyMetadata(false, HandleFocusPropertyChanged));

    private static void HandleFocusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (UIElement)d;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            element.Focus(); // Ignore false values.
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FooProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         Style="{StaticResource EditText}" ui:Initial.Focus="True"/>
```

The original idea came from SO, but couldn't find the answer.
100% free code behind :P

HTH

Comment: Close but not quite. You need to also handle the case where element.IsVisible is false. In that case, you want to add a handler for IsVisibleChanged and when element becomes visible you call Focus() and remove the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem, its working fine with me, try the following code on a new project as a proof of concept and see if it works with you:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="NameTextBox" Text="ddd"
                     IsVisibleChanged="TextBox_IsVisibleChanged" />
        </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            Boolean success = element.Focus(); //Always returns false and doesn't take focus.
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NameTextBox.IsVisible)
            NameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            NameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```